# Visual Studio Code No Display Name Remote SSH

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, x11, x11-forwarding

I am using Visual Studio Code to run my remote python code on another machine. For that I am using the extension Remote SSH within VSCode. When I am trying to run my python file (that saves a matplotlib image) I always get the error :

```
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I already installed an additional extension (Remote X11) and added the line "ForwardX11 yes" to my ssh config file. But still I receive the same error. But when I connect to the terminal via "ssh -X host" then it is working.